# How to draw a Circle of fixed radius in QGIS using QgsMapCanvasItem?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I have derived a class from QgsMapCanvasItem for drawing circle of some radius at a given latitude and longitude.
In my paint function I am using QPainter to draw the circle as

```
void paint (QPainter* painter){
 painter->drawEllipse(center, radius, radius);
} 

void updatePosition(){
   center = toCanvasCoordinates(center_lat_lon);
}
```

The circle is drawing properly and its position is getting updated whenever the events like panning, zoom in, zoom out are happening. 
My problem is, whenever I am zooming in or zomming out, radius is not changing accordingly.  Also I want to update my radius according to the projection system  ( say WGS84 ). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A different approach might work better - especially considering zooming and CRS:

1. In code (you might want to use Python instead of C++), create a memory layer. The memory layer can have a CRS assigned.
2. Then create a circle feature in that memory layer. It will use the CRS units (meters, feet, degree, ...).

If you want just a circle and no ellipse, just use buffer code, e.g.

```
vpoly = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "pointbuffer", "memory")
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(3517601,5406205)).buffer(10000,5))
provider = vpoly.dataProvider()
vpoly.startEditing()
provider.addFeatures( [feature] )
vpoly.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some Python code I am using for drawing [QgsHighlight](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsHighlight.html) circles around point features:

```
def circle_geometry(self, pt, radius=0, segments=0, mapunits=False):
    """
    Draw a circle at a canvas point

    :type pt: qgis.core.QgsPoint
    :param pt: canvas point, in layer crs
    :type radius: float
    :param radius: cicle radius, considered to be in layer units
    :type segments: int
    :param segments: number of segments usually divisible by 8, e.g. 32
    :type mapunits: bool
    :param mapunits: whether the radius should be considered in map units
    :return: QgsGeometry of type QGis.Polygon
    """
    if not radius:
        radius = self.circleradius  # default of 5 for this project
    if not mapunits:
        ctx = self.canvas.mapRenderer().rendererContext()
        # as mm (converted to map pixels, then to map units)
        radius *= ctx.scaleFactor() * ctx.mapToPixel().mapUnitsPerPixel()
    if not segments:
        segments = self.circlesegments  # usually divisible by 8, e.g. 32
    pts = []
    for i in range(segments):
        theta = i * (2.0 * math.pi / segments)
        p = QgsPoint(pt.x() + radius * math.cos(theta),
                     pt.y() + radius * math.sin(theta))
        pts.append(p)
    return QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([pts])
```

While these circles are temporary, erased after a canvas refresh in my case, and not the C++ code you are looking for in your QgsMapCanvasItem subclass, you can see how [QgsRendererContext](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsRenderContext.html) is used to determine what the radius would be given the current map scale.